# If random variable $\xi$ is more peaked than $\eta$ can $P(|\xi| \leqslant |\eta|)$ equals zero?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose, there are two (maybe dependent) random variables $\xi$, $\eta$. Also, it is known that $\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \,\, P(|\xi| \leqslant t) \geqslant P(|\eta| \leqslant t)$. In other words $\xi$ is more peaked about zero than $\eta$.

I struggle with proving that $P(|\xi| \leqslant |\eta|) > 0$.

1. Is it possible anyway? Maybe there is an example of $\xi, \eta$ that ruins this proposition.
2. I tried to prove like this:

Let it be false, so $P(|\xi| \leqslant |\eta|) = 0 \Rightarrow P(|\xi| > |\eta|) = 1$.

It is clear that:

$\forall t \in \mathbb{R} \quad P(|\xi| \leqslant t \,\Big|\, |\xi| > |\eta|) \leqslant P(|\eta| \leqslant t \,\Big | \, |\xi| > |\eta|)$

This implies that $P(|\xi| \leqslant t) \leqslant P(|\eta| \leqslant t) \Rightarrow P(|\xi| \leqslant t) = P(|\eta| \leqslant t)$.

Then I am stuck.
So, I have $P(|\xi| > |\eta|) = 1 \text{ and } \forall t \in \mathbb{R}\quad P(|\xi| \leqslant t) = P(|\eta| \leqslant t)$ and cannot find a controversy, but it seems to be here...

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $P(|\eta|<|\xi|)=1$. Then there exists $t_0>0$ such that $P(|\eta|<t_0<|\xi|)>0$. This can be seen by writing
$$
1=P(|\eta|<|\xi|)=P(\bigcup_{t\in(0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}}\{|\eta|<t<|\xi|\}).
$$
For any $t$ we find that
$$
P(|\eta|\leq t)\geq P(|\eta|<t)=P(|\xi|\leq|\eta|<t)+P(|\eta|<|\xi|\leq t)+P(|\eta|<t<|\xi|).
$$
By choice of $t_0$ this implies that $P(|\eta|\leq t_0)>P(|\eta|<|\xi|\leq t_0)=P(|\xi|\leq t_0)$. This is a contradiction since you assumed that $P(|\eta|\leq t)\leq P(|\xi\leq t)$ for all $t$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is well so far. You could continue for example by considering the moment-generating function. As $|\xi|$ and $|\eta|$ have the same CDF, they also have the same moment-generating function. This leads to
$$\mathbb E\exp(t|\xi|)=\mathbb E\exp(t|\eta|)<\mathbb E\exp(t|\xi|),
$$ since we can use for the inequality $P(|\xi| > |\eta|) = 1$ and the exponential and the integral are strictly monotone. Thus you have the desired contradiction.